# Update Feature Name in Feature Table (MSI) with Wix3 DTF

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to update existing entry in Feature Table in MSI. More specifically, the Feature Identifier itself (first column - Feature).

```
String featureQuery = "SELECT * FROM `Feature`";
view = db.OpenView(featureQuery);
view.Execute();
rec = view.Fetch();
rec.SetString("Feature", "NewName"); <- error here "Function failed during execution"
view.Modify(ViewModifyMode.Update, rec);
```

However, when I do the same but only change "Feature" column to "Title" (in row where error occurs) for example, title column in MSI is changing to "NewName".

So, my question is - does this even possible or I'm making mistake somewhere? If later, please point me where, I would be very grateful. Anyway, any suggestions are very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is the MSI being installed at the time?

Comment: No, I just want to edit exiting MSI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example of mine isn't exactly the same because it's my dumb C# P/Invoke test, but it does work and change the Feature.Feature value, so it is allowed by the APIs, and perhaps there's something that the DTF wrapper classes have in the way of defaults etc that needs changing. The obvious difference is in the SetString/MsiRecordSetString code where the native API requires a field number. I apologize for not looking at the DTF, but SetString presumably maps the "Feature" string to an actual field number to update the first field of the record. If it has an overload that takes a field number, try that one. I'll add that you haven't actually selected a specific feature, so you're at risk of modifying the "first" feature, because select *  will return them all.

```
IntPtr hDb = IntPtr.Zero;
int res = MsiInvoke.MsiOpenDatabase("C:\\Phil\\MyDD\\Samples Setup\\InsertRTF\\setup.msi", MsiInvoke.MSIDBOPEN_TRANSACT, out hDb);

 string qinsert = "SELECT * FROM `Feature`";
 IntPtr hView =IntPtr.Zero;
 res = MsiInvoke.MsiDatabaseOpenView(hDb, qinsert, out hView);
 res = MsiInvoke.MsiViewExecute(hView, 0); 
 IntPtr hRec= IntPtr.Zero;
  res = MsiInvoke.MsiViewFetch(hView, out hRec); 
  res = MsiInvoke.MsiRecordSetString(hRec, 1, "Whatever");
  res = MsiInvoke.MsiViewModify(hView, 4, hRec); // 4 = msimodify_replace 3 = modify_assign 
  res = MsiInvoke.MsiViewClose(hView);
  res = MsiInvoke.MsiDatabaseCommit(hDb);
```

MsiInvoke is just a dumb P/invoke class I created, starting like this:

```
public class MsiInvoke
    {
        //Oops MSIHandles are not IntPtrs. 

        [DllImport("msi", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int MsiOpenDatabase(string filename, int persist, out IntPtr dbhandle);
        public const int MSIDBOPEN_DIRECT = 2;
        public const int MSIDBOPEN_TRANSACT = 1;
```

Comment: Is it possible that ``DTF`` detects the foreign keys in other tables that will be broken by the feature name change? For example in ``FeatureComponents``, ``Directory``, ``Conditions``, ``PublishComponent``, ``Assembly`` and the pig's ear "parent feature" in the Feature table itself [**as illustrated in this entity relationship diagram**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368047(v=vs.85).aspx)? I haven't used DTF in many years. I would be surprised if it detected all of this.

Comment: It's what I thought is the origin of the issue. But, as @PhilDW states it's possible via P/Invoke, so the issue probably lies beyond this interconnections.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, PhilDW, that will do the trick.Only one suggestion - what is this class MsiInvoke? Should I implement it on my own or there is some source/hint of it? p.s. Thx for your book btw, it was a great help :)